# Force a single value base field to be in a separate table?

Tags: entities, database, 9

I have a custom entity type (eg: `myentitytype`), and I would like to add a new base field to it via `hook_entity_base_field_info()`. As I understand it, single value fields (with a cardinality of `1`) will create new columns in the `myentitytype_field_data` table, but multi-value fields will create a new table.

Is it possible to "force" a single-value field to be stored in its own database table, rather than adding columns to the *myentity_field_data* table?

Comment: Can you not add it as config entity fields as opposed to entity base fields? I think they all have their individual tables. (Not sure about the multi / single value fields)

Comment: Yes that's true - a config entity field would put it in a separate table. I was specifically curious about where the logic for base fields makes this decision, and if there were any way to specify. Thanks!

Comment: For anyone curious why: I am considering adding a Geofield as a base field, which has 9 columns. It may result in sparse data if its in the shared table. Other logic will depend on this field, which is why I am considering making it a base field.

Answer (score 5):

[`\Drupal\Core\Entity\Sql\DefaultTableMapping`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Entity%21Sql%21DefaultTableMapping.php/class/DefaultTableMapping/9) is responsible for determining a separate field storage table; its [`allowsSharedTableStorage()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Entity%21Sql%21DefaultTableMapping.php/function/DefaultTableMapping%3A%3AallowsSharedTableStorage/9) method returns a Boolean value basing on four conditions.

```php
public function allowsSharedTableStorage(FieldStorageDefinitionInterface $storage_definition) {
  return !$storage_definition->hasCustomStorage() && $storage_definition->isBaseField() && !$storage_definition->isMultiple() && !$storage_definition->isDeleted();
}
```

The only feasible solution would be to implement your own storage handler and use `"custom_storage" => TRUE`.

Comment: Thanks this is exactly the logic I was looking for! :-)

Comment: FYI: As an alternative solution, I created a proposal for Drupal core that would add a new `hasDedicatedStorage()` method to base field definitions, which would allow developers to explicitly specify that they want dedicated table storage for their single-value base field. https://www.drupal.org/project/drupal/issues/3183359