# How can I properly create separate storage for a base field?

Tags: entities, 9

What is the correct and supported way to create a separate table storage for a base field on a custom entity? I tried [the answer here](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/298251/93997), using `setCustomStorage(TRUE)`, but it didn't work, and I don't think that I need to actually create custom storage, I just wanted a separate table in the database for the field.

I was able to get a separate storage table with `BundleFieldDefinition::create('address')` but I was not sure if it is ok to create a bundle field within the `baseFieldDefinitions`?

From what I understand, the [`BundleFieldDefinition`](https://git.drupalcode.org/project/entity/-/blob/8.x-1.x/src/BundleFieldDefinition.php#L18) class just extends the base field class, and returns `FALSE` on `isBaseField()`.

The snippet below works fine, but is this a supported way of doing it?

```php
/**
 * {@inheritdoc}
 */
public static function baseFieldDefinitions(EntityTypeInterface $entity_type) {
  $fields = parent::baseFieldDefinitions($entity_type);
  $fields['shipping_address'] = BundleFieldDefinition::create('address')
    ->setLabel(t('Shipping Address'))
    ->setDescription(t('The shipping address.'))
    ->setCardinality(1)
    ->setSetting('field_overrides', [AddressField::ADDITIONAL_NAME => ['override' => FieldOverride::HIDDEN]])
    ->setDisplayOptions('form', [
      'type' => 'address_default',
      'weight' => 4,
    ])
    ->setDisplayConfigurable('form', TRUE)
    ->setDisplayConfigurable('view', TRUE);

   return $fields;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To store the field data in a separate database table, you need to override [`ContentEntityBase::bundleFieldDefinitions()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Entity%21ContentEntityBase.php/function/ContentEntityBase%3A%3AbundleFieldDefinitions/9), which is the method for adding bundle fields or overriding base fields. That does not allow to decide the database table name, but only to avoid using a shared database table that otherwise Drupal would use.

For an entity that depends from the [*Entity API*](https://www.drupal.org/project/entity) module, [Defining bundle fields in code](http://www.noreiko.com/blog/defining-bundle-fields-code) shows how to define bundle fields for an entity. In particular, it shows how to define the storage for the added bundle fields.

Supposing that the entity class is `MyEntity` and that the machine name of the module that implements that class is *mymodule*, the code to use in your case would be the following one.

```php
/**
 * Entity class.
 */
class MyEntity /* extends … */ {

  /**
   * Class properties and other methods
   */

  /**
   * {@inheritdoc}
   */
  public static function bundleFieldDefinitions(EntityTypeInterface $entity_type, $bundle, array $base_field_definitions) {
    if ($bundle == 'mybundle') {
      $fields = parent::bundleFieldDefinitions($entity_type, $bundle, array $base_field_definitions);
      $fields['shipping_address'] = BundleFieldDefinition::create('address')
        ->setLabel(t('Shipping Address'))
        ->setDescription(t('The shipping address.'))
        ->setCardinality(1)
        ->setSetting('field_overrides', [AddressField::ADDITIONAL_NAME => ['override' => FieldOverride::HIDDEN]])
        ->setDisplayOptions('form', ['type' => 'address_default', 'weight' => 4])
        ->setDisplayConfigurable('form', TRUE)
        ->setDisplayConfigurable('view', TRUE);

      return $fields;
    }
  }

  /**
   * Other methods
   */

}
```

```php
/**
 * mymodule.module
 */

/**
 * Implements hook_entity_field_storage_info().
 */
function mymodule_entity_field_storage_info(EntityTypeInterface $entity_type) {
  if ($entity_type->id() == 'myentity') {
    return MyEntity::bundleFieldDefinitions($entity_type, 'mybundle', []);
  }
}
```

Comment: There's no "custom" database table, but the field gets it's own table, as it would if it was multi-valued. So is your answer saying create the bundle field under bundle field definitions? I've not found any modules that create bundle fields that way as an example.

Comment: That's correct: Drupal only allows fields to get their own database table, but not which database table is used for them. Field types decide the schema for their database table, though, whenever that is shared or not.

Comment: As for entities that use `bundleFieldDefinitions()`, there are two entities implemented by Drupal core: the *Comment* entity with [`Comment::bundleFieldDefinitions()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21modules%21comment%21src%21Entity%21Comment.php/function/Comment%3A%3AbundleFieldDefinitions/9), and the *Taxonomy term* entity with [`Term::bundleFieldDefinitions()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21modules%21taxonomy%21src%21Entity%21Term.php/function/Term%3A%3AbundleFieldDefinitions/9).

Comment: I extended the answer to explain how entity field items define their database schema. That still does not allow to choose a database table name for the data of a specific entity field used for a specific entity. Changing the entity field item plugin can change the database schema, but that is all Drupal core allows, at the moment.

Comment: I was speaking about examples that use BundleFieldDefinition::create()

Comment: I don't think there are any examples in drupal core where  ```BundleFieldDefinition::create()``` is called in an entity.

Comment: Drupal core does not use a class defined by a contributed module. Drupal core should define its own `BundleFieldDefinition`, and there is an issue for that, but so far it has not been implemented. (Actually, Drupal core has a field definition class for bundle fields, but it has a different name and its instances are created differently from what done with the contributed `BundleFieldDefinition` class.)

Comment: Read this multiple times, and it all still seems somewhat convoluted. My module depends upon commerce, which depends upon entity module.

Comment: Are you defining a custom entity in a module that depends on the Commerce Core module?

Comment: In this case, what is the name of the entity class? What is the module machine name?

Comment: Yup. CommercePurchaseOrder. commerce_purchasing. But I decided instead to allow users to install their own address field.

Comment: Looking at your updated answer, what if I want the field available for all bundles? Can I not specify the bundle in the definition, and in the field storage?

Comment: If a field is available for all the bundles, then it is not anymore a bundle field. In that case, the `baseFieldDefinitions()` method or the `hook_entity_base_field_info()` implementation can return data about that field.

Comment: Well, I guess back to the original question of separate storage for base field.